# When insert query run for multiple times the primary key is not increased properly

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in my database.
dummy & main.
Both the table contains same field. Table dummy contains about 100 records. Now I have to copy all the data from this dummy table into main table 5 times. I am using the query below. My issue is with primary key. For the first time the data inserted has primary key till 100 then second time the primary key is something like 170 instead of 101.

This is the query that I have used.

```
insert into main(com_name, com_address, com_lat, com_lon, coverageArea_population)
(SELECT com_name, com_address, com_lat, com_lon, coverageArea_population
 FROM dummy)
```

Comment: First of all, the query you showed us is inserting data _into_ dummy _from_ main, not the other way around.  Second, you do not need to be concerned with the sequence of the primary key, as MySQL will manage this internally for you most of the time.  Just accept whatever value you get.

Comment: What is your primary key?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes i changed it to main table.

Comment: @Yuri what do you mean what is my primary key .

Comment: Why do you care about the _value_ of the primary key, so long as it upholds its contract of being unique?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen my concern is what is causing that issue. Yes its not a big thing to care about.

Comment: Things like deletion or doing multiple inserts at the same time can cause this.